# How to open an Activity on Keyguard android studio?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

i have an App which is running good, but now i want to open that app on Keyguard 
i mean while my phone is lock i can still able to open my app 
like Camera App while the phone is call we can still use camera just like that i want to open my app without opening the lockscreen 
help me what should i do to make this work 
have edited the xml file 
home_screen | keyguard 
as a widget but its not working 
can anyone help me on this !!

Comment: htmlentities http://ca1.php.net/htmlentities

Comment: @ArunKillu - post it as answer, not as comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `htmlspecialchars()` function after replacing the smileys with HTML Tags. It will not work correctly.
Output will be as

`<strong>Name :</strong> I am Happy <img src="happy.png">`

There are two solution to make it work.

**Soln 1 :**

Don't convert the text into emoticons before storing it in database. While showing it to the user.

First use `htmlspecialchars()`, then use `strireplace()`.

**Soln 2:**

First convert the whole message using `htmlspecialchars()` , then convert the emoticons using `strireplace()`. After that, Store the result in the database.

Comment: okay but now i have one more problem 
now everything is working good.. thank you for that but now again 
when i type <3 or </3 the heart symbol .png is not appearing.. can u help me with that too...??

Comment: Instead of replacing <3 to <img src='heart.png'> , replace &lt;3 to <img src='heart.png'>

Answer (score 2):

Run the `str_ireplace` code to insert the smilies **after** you use `htmlspecialchars` instead of before.